# Google Maps API stopped working when I added a port number to the URL

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've been successfully using Google Maps API 3 for an internal web app using XAMPP server for a while, using the free access key provided to me by Google. I now want to expose this app to the internet, but I don't want to open port 80, so I set Apache to listen to another port (let's say 2880) and set up port forwarding. I am now able to access the web app at this port over the internet, but after Google Maps briefly loads the image it disappears, with a message to check the Javascript console. When I do, I see error messages such as 'MissingKeyMapError' and 'NoApiKeys'.

I registered for my Google API Key with a particular URL, but it didn't have a port associated with it.

Can someone suggest what I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: your webserver may be listening on that port, but are you sure that all code will be using that port as well, e.g. an ajax call with a hard-coded `:80` will run into a cross-domain error.

Comment: Register the key for the complete URL including the port number.

Comment: Thanks, geocodezip, but I've tried this and it still doesn't work. I'm still working on it, so will report back.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You need to register the port number as well in the URL Origin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the console, maybe you missed the API KEY in the call of the map.